# NLog Header (Ignore layout)

Tags: c#, logging, nlog

Is is possible to write a line to the log file that's not a log?

I'd like to write a "Note" that will ignore the layout in my NLog.config and just write the text exactly as I pass it for one or two lines.

This could be used for writing a header on the log file.

I'm not sure if this will matter to the solution but I'm using a separate ClassLogger (`LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()`) for every class and it's not an option for me to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do this with a few creative rules.

First in my code I created a logger specifically for the header like this:

```cs
var loggerNoLayout = LogManager.GetLogger("NoLayout");
loggerNoLayout.Info("<Header Line 1>");
loggerNoLayout.Info("<Header Line 2>");
loggerNoLayout.Info("<Header Line 3>");
```

Then I modified my NLog.config like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <targets>
        <target name="NoLayout"
                xsi:type="File"
                fileName="${specialfolder:folder=Desktop}\LogFile.log"
                layout="${message}" />
        <target name="FileTrace"
                xsi:type="File"
                fileName="${specialfolder:folder=Desktop}\LogFile.log"
                layout="${level:padding=-5:fixedLength=true} | ${logger:padding=-62:fixedLength=true:alignmentOnTruncation=right}| ${date:format=HH\:mm\:ss} | ${message:padding=-100}"
                deleteOldFileOnStartup="true" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
        <logger writeTo="NoLayout"
                levels="Info"
                name="NoLayout"
                final="true" />
        <logger writeTo="FileTrace"
                minlevel="Trace"
                name="*" />
    </rules>
</nlog>
```

The key here is that the `NoLayout` target's layout only writes the message and the rule for writing to `NoLayout` only works if the logger is named `NoLayout`.  The final step is to add the `final="true"` so that my normal (`FileTrace`) logger does not pick up the header logs.

Answer (score 0):

Sure.  Write a string to the log that starts with a newline.  Then write your content.

```
var longMultilineMessage = "pretend this variable contains\n a long multiline message";
logger.Info($"\n{longMultilineMessage}");
```

will show up in logs as :

```
2017-01-01 INFO
pretend this variable contains 
a long multiline message
```

Comment: You don't want your multiline message timestamped?